# Passing a number of arguments for spliting a vector into consecutive tranches

Tags: r

Need to split a long vector into chunks of unequal size consecutively.

```
subsum<-(c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,0,0,0,9,8,7,6,6,5,4,4,5,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,3))
cuts<- c(list(5),list(15),list(20))
# I can do one as follows
split(subsum, ceiling(seq_along(subsum)/10))
# How could I do three sublists consecutively. The below example does not work. 
split(subsum, ceiling(seq_along(subsum)/seq_along(5,15,20)))

# Desired output is:  

[[1]]
1,2,3,4,3
[[2]] 
2,1,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,0
[[3]]
0,0,9,8,7,6,6,5,4,4,5,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,3
```

EDITED QUESTION FOR IMPUT IN FORM OF LIST OF VECTORS AS THIS IS HOW IT IS GIVEN

```
# The imput comes as a list of vectors with the following output in the form of I have changed the form. 
LL
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 15

[[3]]
[1] 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
subsum <- c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,0,0,0,9,8,7,6,6,5,4,4,5,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,3)
cuts   <- c(5,15,20)
group  <- rep(1:length(cuts), times=cuts)
split(subsum, group)
```

?

Comment: if cuts numbers are given non coma separated how would you sort it out

Comment: Edited the question - well not really as the imput comes as a list with the following output in the form of > LL [[1]] [1] 5 [[2]] [1] 15 [[3]] [1] 20 which results in

Comment: what about `cuts <- unlist(cuts)`?

Comment: Yes though so appologies and thanks